# Should I enable my Mobo Raid controller or leave it at AHCI?

Tags: raid, disk, sata, ahci

I am setting up a raid storage volume, should I leave the sata controller on AHCI or switch it to raid when using Ubuntu's software side raid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave it on AHCI when you intend using software RAID/mdadm. Using any functionality of your motherboard could result in incompatibility with other boards or controllers.